Is it possible to perform Rolling Origins on multiple time series with the modeltime package in R?
I am currently working on a project that involves multiple time series, and I would like to know if it is possible to implement a Rolling Origins technique for these multiple series using the modeltime package in R.
I found very few examples on the internet of what I'm trying to do in R. I am using modeltime because I am familiar with working with tidymodels, but I am open to other methods or packages.
Here is a sample code I found on the internet that is quite close to what I am trying to achieve:
data_tbl <- walmart_sales_weekly %>%
    select(id, date = Date, value = Weekly_Sales)

nested_data_tbl <- data_tbl %>%
    extend_timeseries(
        .id_var        = id,
        .date_var      = date,
        .length_future = 52
    ) %>%
    nest_timeseries(
        .id_var        = id,
        .length_future = 52,
        .length_actual = 52*2
    ) %>%
    split_nested_timeseries(
        .length_test = 52
    )

rec_prophet <- recipe(value ~ date, extract_nested_train_split(nested_data_tbl)) 

wflw_prophet <- workflow() %>%
    add_model(
      prophet_reg("regression", seasonality_yearly = TRUE) %>% 
        set_engine("prophet")
    ) %>%
    add_recipe(rec_prophet)

nested_modeltime_tbl <- modeltime_nested_fit(
  nested_data = nested_data_tbl,
  wflw_prophet,
)

But now I would like to for gradually shifting the origin of the dataset to iteratively make forecasts, reassessing the model each time. But I can't get it to work.
Therefore, if you have any methods to achieve what I'm trying to do, even if it involves using a different package, please let me know.
Thank you in advance for your help!
